# Installing mdbtools on CentOS

Tags: centos, glib

I'm attepting to install [mdbtools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/) on CentOS and whilst running `./configure` I get the following:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.0.0... no
Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...
The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
exact error that occured. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed.

glib 2.0 is required by MDB Tools.
It can be downloaded at www.gtk.org.
```

GLIB is definitely installed though so I'm struggling. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdbtools` is packaged in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), so you can add that repo and install it with yum, which is the preferred way to install software on CentOS (and any other distribution).

What you are lacking though to install from source code is likely the development package of `glib`  containing the C header files.

Comment: I was missing the glib2-devel package in centos 6.

Comment: `mdbtools` is available in the EPEL 7. It is not available in the EPEL 8 anymore. I found it in the Raven repo: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/raven-x86_64/mdbtools-0.7.1-13.el8.x86_64.rpm.html